# C# - Close the opened browser which has my url

Tags: c#

How to close the opened browser with my url,

Current am trying with below code, it is working if browser is not running for anything else. So my code open the browser and do my process and close it.

In case browser is already opened with other use, my code the open new browser but closing all opened browsers. I want to close only last browser which i opened through code.

```
//Main program
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
int procCnt = localByName.Count();
if (procCnt == 0)
{
      Process proc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "https://www.web.com/");
      killChildren(proc.Id);
}
else if (procCnt >= 1)
{
      Process proc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "https://www.web.com/");
      int existIEid = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < localByName.Count(); i++)
      {
            existIEid = localByName[i].Id;
      }  
      killChildren(existIEid);
}

//Kill process
private static void killChildren(int parentPID)
{
      ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
                ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + parentPID);
      ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
      foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
      {
          killChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
      }
      try
      {
          Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(parentPID);
          proc.Kill();
      }
      catch (ArgumentException)
      {
          // Process already exited.
      }
  }
```

Observed in task manager, "iexplorer" is consider as parent and "iexplorer *32" is consider as children.
If browser is already opened, newly opened browser is act as children and am facing issue to close it.

Myself need to close only the last one which i open through code. How to do it? Please give me an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't. Once you launch a browser, the user thinks of it as *theirs*, not your program's. So they might open extra tabs, navigate around, etc, and have completely forgotten that it was opened due to something your program did. And they're familiar with how to close browser windows when done. The only "browser" you really have control over is if you host a web browser control of some form *within* your own program's UI.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Good to know about it. Could you please suggest where i could find to design my UI. Then as you said i can control it. Thanks

Comment: @dkprogrammer that's a whole other question

Comment: Oh okay, Sorry to ask here itself.